# Cursors Or While Loop what will be a good option to work on 6,00,000+ rows data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012-web

I have a table_A where i imported a data from .csv file. I want to compare some of the columns from table_A with table_B and accordingly insert a data into a table and update a status to table_A.
what should i use While loop or Cursor.. Plz do suggest

```
DECLARE @A_2 VARCHAR(10), @A_3 VARCHAR(50), @A_4 VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT A_2, A_3, A_4 FROM Temp_table

OPEN db_cursor  
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor   
    INTO @A_2, @A_3, @A_4 
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
    If @A_2 <> (SELECT C_2 FROM Table_C where C_2= @A_2)
        UPDATE Temp_table SET [Status]='Not Exits in Table_C'
    ELSE BEGIN
       IF @A_3=(Select B_3 from Table_B where B_3=@A_3) AND @A_2=(SELECT B_2              FROM Table_B where B_2= @A_2)
       UPDATE Temp_table SET [Status]='Duplicate Row, Already Exists'
       ELSE 
            IF (@A_4 <>'B_4 '+'B_5')
            UPDATE Temp_table SET [Status]=' Format is not accepted '
            ELSE
            INSERT INTO Table_B(B_2, B_3, B_4) VALUES(@A_2, @A_3, @A_4)

    END
  CLOSE db_cursor  DEALLOCATE db_cursor    
  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor  INTO @A_2, @A_3, @A_4
    END
```

Here Temp_table is the table where i will be importing data from .csv file and comparison will be done using columns of Table_B, Table_C with Temp_Table
will it be correct way to do?

Comment: The big mind-shift with relational databases is to get away from procedural thinking - while and curosrs - and get into thinking about sets. SQL is great at comparing huge amounts of data and acting on it. Embrace SQL!

Comment: Neither, use set-based queries instead.

Comment: Bit open ended, and other options are available, depending on performance you could use a straight query (no need for a loop or cursor, set based approach would be better), or use SSIS as an option for more linear thinking if the data set gets too large / perf is an issue

Comment: If you wish to share some sample data, how you plan to compare them, and  what you intend to insert into a new table as a result, we can help out writing that SQL. Most likely all three of those steps is 1 SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with performance, but I would not recommend a while loop because it will be really slow. I would do something from like:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.column1 = table2.column1,
    table1.column2 = table2.column2
WHERE (do a select statement or column comparison)
```

This is just a general guideline and I hope it can help you get started. Otherwise you'll have to be a lot more specific.

References for updating and comparing:

[How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server?rq=1)

[Microsoft UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Neither. If you're working with SQL, the first step is to move away from thinking procedurally and move towards set-based thinking.

To do what you're looking to do, use a `MERGE`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

**SETUP**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table_A') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #table_A

CREATE TABLE #table_A (col1 int, col2 int, colX int, checkme bit DEFAULT 0) ;
INSERT INTO #table_A (col1, col2, colX)
VALUES 
      (1,1,1)
    , (2,2,2)
    , (3,3,3)
    , (4,4,4)
;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table_B') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #table_B

CREATE TABLE #table_B (col1 int, col2 int, colX int) ;
INSERT INTO #table_B (col1, col2, colX)
VALUES 
      (0,0,1)
    , (0,0,2)
;
```

**BEFORE**

```
SELECT * FROM #table_A ;     
SELECT * FROM #table_B ;
```

**QUERY TIME**

```
MERGE #table_B AS target  
USING ( SELECT col1, col2, colX FROM #table_A ) AS source (col1, col2, colX)  
ON (target.colX = source.colX)  
WHEN MATCHED THEN   
    UPDATE SET col1 = source.col1
        , col2 = source.col2 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
    INSERT (col1, col2)  
    VALUES (source.col1, source.col2) 
;
```

**AFTER**

```
SELECT * FROM #table_A ;     
SELECT * FROM #table_B ;
```

I *think* you can also use the `MERGE` to update the flag in `#table_A`, but I don't know the correct syntax. If you need to, you can also just run another `UPDATE` after the `MERGE`.

**MARK TABLE_A FLAG**

```
UPDATE #table_A
SET flag = 1
FROM #table_B
WHERE #table_A.col1 = #table_B.col1
    AND #table_A.col2 = #table_B.col1
    AND #table_B.colX IS NOT NULL
;
```

**AFTER AFTER**
    SELECT * FROM #table_A ;

*MORE `MERGE` GOODIES:* http://www.made2mentor.com/2012/07/got-the-urge-to-merge/

Answer (score -1):

If you want to improve performance then you need to look at SET based operations. While loop and cursor is basically the same thing.

Refer the  Below link for more details

```
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/comparing-cursor-vs-while-loop-performance-in-sql-server-2008/
```